# What is $\int\frac{x^4}{1+ e^x} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Here's the integral I have,

> $$ \displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^4}{1+ e^x} dx $$

I tried the usual methods I know, but I failed miserably.

How would you all approach this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to calculate this integral? I suspect that you actually have another problem which involves this integral.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @md2perpe Not really I'm just playing around with integrals. (Even though I'm a rookie)

Comment: The integral is very similar to the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857795/how-to-solve-improper-integrals-i-cant-integrate).

Comment: @md2perpe Yea I know, I did check that a while back, but it wasn't much help :(

Comment: Not all [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) have a primitive function that is an elementary function. This is probably such a case.

Comment: @md2perpe Trust me, everytime I thought that an integral wont have an elementary solution, someone came and surprised me. So I can't say for sure.

Comment: RayDansh has given you probably the best answer you can get for the indefinite integral, but if you'd only wanted the $\int_0^\infty dx$ value it would've been easier, viz. $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^4 e^{-x}dx}{1+e^{-x}}=24\eta(5)=\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5)$.

Comment: @J.G. ikr, that's why I said, it's hard cuz it's indefinite :(

Comment: may be he mean $\displaystyle \int^{a}_{-a}\frac{x^4}{1+e^x}dx,a>0$

Answer (score 4):

According to WolframAlpha, you would have to use nonelementary functions such as the polylogarithm function, $\operatorname{Li}_n(x)$:
$$\frac{x^5}{5} - x^4 \log(1 + e^x) - 4 x^3 \operatorname{Li}_2(-e^x) + 12 x^2 \operatorname{Li}_3(-e^x) - 24 x \operatorname{Li}_4(-e^x) + 24 \operatorname{Li}_5(-e^x)$$

Comment: +1 .... Is it just me or does anyone here shy away from polylogarithms too?

Answer (score 4):

$\int\frac {x^4}{1+e^x} \ dx\\
\int\frac {x^4e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} \ dx$

Converting to a geometric series: $\frac {y}{1+y} = \sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty (-y)^n$

$\int x^4\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty (-1)^ne^{-nx} \ dx$

considering just one term $\int x^4e^{-nx} = (\frac {x^4}{n} + \frac {4x^3}{n^2} + \frac {12x^2}{n^2} + \frac {24x}{n^3} + \frac {24}{n^4}) e^{-nx}$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\frac {x^4}{n} + \frac {4x^3}{n^2} + \frac {12x^2}{n^2} + \frac {24x}{n^3} + \frac {24}{n^4}) e^{-nx}$

It is worth noting
$\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty} \frac {x^{s-1}}{e^x -1} \ dx = \zeta(s)$

Comment: I am a big fan of this approach to integrals. Can be used to solve one of the greatest integrals of all time, namely $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{p-1}}{e^x - 1} dx = \zeta(p) \Gamma(p)$

Comment: looks like your ninja edit beat me to it!

Comment: @packetpacket thx... It usually takes me 3 revisions before I am satisfied with most of my answers.

Comment: It would be nice to remember that we can exchange integral with the series because of the uniform convergence :)

Comment: @DougM Sir, shouldn't the geometric series be $ \frac{-y}{1+y}$ instead of $\frac{y}{1+y}$ ?